# Is there a way to include 'time spent' into pageview call in Adobe Analytics?

Tags: adobe-analytics, adobe-launch

I would like to have 'time spent on page' variable as part of the pageview call on subsequent pageview. Is there a way to store this into a variable?

Comment: There is already native Time spent on page dimension available in Adobe Analytics. Is there some reason you want to create your own custom solution?